# how to start console screen in windows service

Tags: c#, logging, windows-services

i use Tow methods to log my application (windows app) to file and console screen

```
public static void InitLogFile(string filename)
{

    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
    Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(fs));
    Trace.AutoFlush = true;

}
public static void InitConsole()
{
    Trace.Listeners.Add(new ConsoleTraceListener());
    Trace.AutoFlush = true;
}
```

and i use this code for start the console screen when my windows application is started

```
  [DllImport("kernel32.dll",EntryPoint = "GetStdHandle",SetLastError = true,CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll",EntryPoint = "AllocConsole",SetLastError = true,CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private static extern int AllocConsole();


        private const int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11;
        private const int MY_CODE_PAGE = 437;

        void StartConsole()
        {
            AllocConsole();
            IntPtr stdHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
            var safeFileHandle = new SafeFileHandle(stdHandle, true);
            var fileStream = new FileStream(safeFileHandle, FileAccess.Write);
            var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(MY_CODE_PAGE);
            var standardOutput = new StreamWriter(fileStream, encoding) {AutoFlush = true};
            Console.SetOut(standardOutput);
        }
```

**My Question is :**

I convert my windows Application to `windows service`  the console log screen is not working not appearing now how make it work?

Answer (score 2):

A Windows Service does not run like a standard Windows application. It could be running when no users are logged on to the computer so how could a console screen appear?

When running as a service you should consider writing to the Windows Event Log or some other logging mechanism instead.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you don't see anything is because of [Session 0 Isolation](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/04/27/application-compatibility-session-0-isolation.aspx).

However, there is a nice codeproject [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35773/Subverting-Vista-UAC-in-Both-32-and-64-bit-Archite) which will run an app from a service, in the user session.

Just put your code into a exe file, and launch the exe file using the project in the link.

Comment: true, but the reason Session 0 isolation is there is because Windows Services should not be interactive. Running in the user session is a nice "hack" if you need to debug the service, for example, but should not be used in production. Otherwise, why create a service in the beginning?

Comment: Yeah, but I am just answering the question as given, and if they want to create a service to do it then they can use this way. I agree it's not necessary and there are better ways, but this just answers the questions requirements.

Comment: right, just pointing out that @tito11 should ask himself if what he's asking for is good, and reason more if the console window is a good or bad idea